# How can I create a daily PowerPoint Presentation with data pulled from a web server/service without relying on office (or interops)?

Tags: xml, vb.net, powerpoint

To elaborate a bit more on the title:

We have a web service that we hit for daily report information - it is returned in XML. I need to use this XML data (that is in no particular order) and format it for a daily PowerPoint Presentation. The catch is, we cannot have Office on our server (or use interops).

We currently have something that gets the job done. A PowerPoint template with all (thought of) possible situations the data could come in (it can change often of course - i.e. Three slides of tables, five slides of text, etc.) The code for formatting is used in VB which formats accordingly and clones slides as needed. Once the formatting of the XML data is finished for the PPT, all excess template slides are deleted.

I have searched around and looked at Java's Apache POI, .NET's NPOI, Apache OpenOffice, and Python's python-pptx.

I feel as though there has to be a better way to do this out there and I am just missing it. Any help or suggestions is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either commit to one of the frameworks you listed above, or you could do the processing/creation of the PowerPoint on a different machine that has Office/Interop installed and then simply copy the PowerPoint to the other server that can't have Office/Interop installed.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend that you take a look at [SlideMight](http://www.slidemight.com), a utility for merging data with PowerPoint templates; both text and images, in slides and tables. The usage is in principle similar to mail merge, with some more advanced stuff.

Disclaimer: I am the developer and seller of SlideMight.

We currently have only licenses for desktop usage; please contact us if you are interested to use it on a server.